# how to extract notes from a mobi book?

Tags: kindle, amazon, annotations, send-to-kindle, footnotes

How can I extract highlighted text, [stored](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1204/9853) in a `.mbp` file?

This specific book was sent to the Kindle as a `.mobi` converted from an `EPUB`.  Is there maybe an operation to regenerate `My Clippings`?  Or, something along those lines?

Comment: Is this [mbp reader](http://www.angelfire.com/ego2/idleloop/mbp_reader.html) helpful?

Comment: @Valentin I think that I tried that, but will have to take another look.